# play2: `play test` show invalid Chinese characters, how to fix?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.0, cjk

I write some tests in a play2 project, which contains some Chinese characters.

When I run:

```
play test
```

There are some tests failed, but the message are not valid Chinese characters:

```
[info]  Message(NotAssigned,Some(Nil),Some(418775910),None,http://v.163.com/video/2011/11/3/H/V7HANAE3H.html#sd=V7HANAE3H&ld=V68F7O9J5&nvp=v.163.com/video/2011/11/3/H/V7HANAE3H
[info] 鍙戦濂芥瓕 銆愭彁绀猴細姝ょ敤鎴锋鍦ㄤ娇鐢≦+聽Web锛
[info] http://web.qq.com/
[info] 銆懧?222,imported_html,Sat Nov 19 18:08:47 CST 2011,None,None,None) did n
```

These strings `鍙戦濂芥瓕 銆愭彁绀猴細姝ょ敤鎴锋鍦ㄤ娇鐢≦+聽Web锛` are unreadable.

I'm on Windows7 x64, with latest play2 source. And all my sources are configured in "UTF-8".

My friend said he uses `sbt` directly to run tests with Chinese characters, which show very good in cmd (windows). So I wonder if I miss something, or play2 doesn't configure it well.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

you might modify the build.scala file under project directory  as the following to force javac 
output message in english.

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here 
      javacOptions ++= Seq("-J-Duser.language", "EN")
    )